# Convertir una imagen a base64 - Javascript

Tags: javascript, base64

¿Cómo hago una función parecida a la siguiente, pero en Javascript?

```
// PHP file
<?php 
$path = 'images/imagen.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

algo como:

```
// JS file
convertirImagen(url){
  ...
  return url;
};
console.log(convertirImagen('images/imagen.png')); // base 64 de imagen
```

La idea es sólo pasar un parámetro y que me devuelva el string en base64 para usarlo de esta forma:

```
var imagen = document.getElementById('miimagen');
imagen.setAttribute('src', convertirImagen('images/imagen.png');
```

Antes vi esta opción pero no entiendo el uso del `callback` y busco una forma de simplificarlo

```
function imgToBase64(url, callback) {
    if (!window.FileReader) {
      callback(null);
      return;
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                callback(reader.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la edición!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar un canvas, dibujarlo a traves de la imagen que quieras y obtener el codigo base64 que deseas

```js
function getBase64Image(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  return dataURL;
}

var base64 = getBase64Image(document.getElementById("img"));
console.log(base64);
```

```html
<img id="img" src="http://static.13.cl/7/sites/all/themes/portal/resources/images/logo_13cl-2x.png">
```

*Nota : Este codigo no funcionara en el `snippet` por temas de seguridad hacia la imagen.*

Answer (score 0):

Usando [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

1. Creamos un nuevo **FileReader** `fileReader`.
2. Se le añade un evento de tipo `load` a `fileReader` que sera ejecutado una vez este cargada la imagen, del cual podremos extraer la imagen en **base64**,
   accediendo a la propiedad `fileReader.result`.
3. Se usa un [callback](http://anexsoft.com/p/112/javascript-que-son-como-usar-y-ejemplos-del-uso-de-callbacks) porque `FileReader` es asíncrono, por tanto hay que pasarle una función, que sera llamada una vez termine de cargar la imagen.
4. Finalmente le decimos a `fileReader` que lea la imagen como una url de datos, a través del método `readAsDataURL(img)`, `file` deber ser un objeto de tipo **File**.

```js
/*
* @param { img }: File
* @param { callback }: function 
*/
function getBase64FomFile(img, callback){
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.addEventListener('load' function(evt){
    callback(fileReader.result);
  });
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(img);
}

/* Seria usada de la siguiente manera */
getBase64FromFile(file, function(base64){
  console.log(base64)
});
```

*Nota : El snippet no funcionara*

Comment: Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: muchas gracias por aclararme el funcionamiento de  la función, sobretodo la parte del _callback_.
Si no me equivoco al usar fileReader se asume que se está usando un input type file para subir la imagen, como puedo hacerlo pero pasando un string con la url?
El caso es que debo generar un pdf y pensaba en la librería pdfMake o pdfjs, debo usar imágenes variables. Ponía el ejemplo con la función de php por que me resulto muy cómodo cuando lo probaba, ¿sabes cómo puedo ejecutar esa función, la de php, con ajax cada vez que necesite una imagen en base 64? y usarla asi en el pdf